# 2 Raspberry Pis 1 Battery

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, pi-zero-w, battery

I'm working on a project, here's the deal...
I have 2 raspberry pis (3B, and a zero w) and 1 battery (3.7V LiIon 1200mAh).
I bought a PowerBoost 1000 (A *"DC/DC boost converter module can be powered by any 3.7V LiIon/LiPoly battery, and convert the battery output to 5.2V"*).

I'm planning on adding a 3.5 TFT screen to the pi zero, I would like to power both raspberry pis with the PowerBoost. Is this possible?

If not, is there a way to use the GPIO pins of the raspberry pi 3B to power the Pi zero?

Comment: You can run both, but it will only run for an hour. It is possible to draw ~1A from the 5V pin on the Pi3 header, and you could use this to run a Zero, although it is difficult to imagine why.

Comment: 3.7V at 1.2 Amp boosted to 5.2V would be below 1 Amp. Don't think the Pi 3B would would run on 1 Amp.

Comment: @bstipe: The battery is rated at 1200mAh ...  However, that does not mean that the battery can source a maximum of 1.2 Amps at 3.7 V.  It means that it can supply 1.2 Amps at 3.7 V for one hour.  If the current demand is more than 1.2 Amps, then the amount of time until discharge is shorter than one hour.   ... in reference to "Can the battery supply the necessary current to run multiple Pi modules as well as a screen?"  ... I don't know.  Give it a try on one module and the screen... and then add another module while measuring the voltage output of the DC-DC converter; if it drops below 5V.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't that be possible? The only drawback is the need for a "power distributor", from say one USB-A to two USB-micro (or USB-C) - which I have never seen one -.
One solution would to be to split two usb cables and connect them together by hand, and done deal.
Also as others have pointed out, depending on the battery capacity you would only have minutes to hours of energy to use. That would be solved by using a beefier boost converter and battery.